# NULL help in T_SQL script

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008R2, I am using this script:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.ea1, 
       b.ea2 
FROM   database1table1 AS a 
WHERE  a.id LIKE N'Active;
```

The result set looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+
| Row | ID  |      EA1      |      EA2      |
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+
|   1 |   1 |  wf@email.co  |  NULL         |
|   2 |   1 |  NULL         |  wf2@email.co |
|   3 |   1 |  NULL         |  NULL         |
|   4 |   2 |  NULL         |  NULL         |
|   5 |   3 |  wf3@email.co |  NULL         |
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

etc.

ID = business number.

EA = email address.

In the above output, there are three rows where ID=1, but only two of those have email addresses.

I want my result to output the rows where there is no email address.  So for this example, the output should only include rows where ID=2.

I have tried adding this WHERE clause:

```
AND (a.EA1 IS NULL) AND (a.EA2 IS NULL);
```

It's still returning rows where ID=1, because one of the rows there has no email address.

Can anyone please suggest an amendment to my script which would only return the row where ID=2?

Many thanks

Comment: So for my output I do not want to see Business IDs 1 or 3, just business ID 2..You meant business id 3 ?

Comment: I just want to see ID 2. ID 3 has an email address (EA1), so I don't want to see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ID,MAX(ROW) AS RW,MAX(EA1) AS EA1,MAX(EA2) AS EA2
FROM #TEMP GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE EA1 IS NULL AND EA2 IS NULL
```

**Output:**

```
ID  RW  EA1 EA2
2   4   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried your suggested idea but it still brought through all data -  so I saw IDs where we had a EA contact. I only want to see IDs where all instances of the ID are NULL.

Comment: @WillF:see attached output i got,can you paste your query

Comment: Apologies I blundered (was working too fast): your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tbl T
WHERE
    T.EA1 IS NULL AND
    T.EA2 IS NULL AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM Tbl IT
        WHERE
            IT.ID = T.ID AND
            (
                IT.EA1 IS NOT NULL OR
                IT.EA2 IS NOT NULL
            )
    )
```